# Why is my object getting clipped when I render?

Tags: rendering, error

Im trying to render a tree but whenever i render it, the background seems to clip the tree.
Heres what im talking about: By the trunk of the tree is where the error is.
[image]

Here is the blender file: [tree.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rba4dsd08lkrmb/tree.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plane that is hidden from the viewport,
but is enabled for rendering.

[image]

[image]
Delete it or disable it for rendering.

[image]

Just as a reminder:

The **Eye** icon is to toggle object visibility on the 3D viewport.

The **Arrow** Icon toggles selectability.

The **Camera** Icon toggles rendering.

Comment: @Tfahami If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted using the check-mark below the voting buttons. Thanks :)